# MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving lib\model.js:297:18 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I got stuck at this mongoose code. I tried billions of time for this. but in my node app.js output is : MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
at D:\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:297:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

**and also data didn't save on mongoose shell. on some my research on internet i found one answer that if you dont provide '_id' then mongoose will do it automatically. On my code I didn't provide any _id. Now this didnt work also. If i tried with provide _id this also didnt work. What should I do now? Please, save my life!!!**

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    address: String
});
const People= mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);
const person = new People(
    {
        name: "john",
        age: 25,
        address: "New York, USA"
},
{ 
    name: "Don",
    age: 30,
    address: "Chicago, USA"
},
{
    name: "Kahn",
    age: 34,
    address: "Dhaka, Bangladesh"
}
);
person.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new People()` constructor is when you are adding 1 new document.

If you want to add multiple documents the command is:

```
await People.insertMany({
    name: "john",
    age: 25,
    address: "New York, USA"
},
{ 
    name: "Don",
    age: 30,
    address: "Chicago, USA"
},
{
    name: "Kahn",
    age: 34,
    address: "Dhaka, Bangladesh"
})
```

Note: im using the promises so you will need `async` at the top of teh function, if you want to provide a callback add `.exec()` after the updateMany

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's document instance can only save one document per time. If you want to add multiple documents then you'll have to rely on MongoDb's native [insertMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) operation.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  address: String,
})
const People = mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema)
await People.insertMany([
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: 25,
    address: 'New York, USA',
  },
  {
    name: 'Don',
    age: 30,
    address: 'Chicago, USA',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kahn',
    age: 34,
    address: 'Dhaka, Bangladesh',
  },
])
```

or with callback approach...

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  address: String,
})
const People = mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema)
People.insertMany([
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: 25,
    address: 'New York, USA',
  },
  {
    name: 'Don',
    age: 30,
    address: 'Chicago, USA',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kahn',
    age: 34,
    address: 'Dhaka, Bangladesh',
  },
], (error, docs) => console.log(docs))
```

Comment: I copied your whole code. and paste it to my code editor.  And also there show a new error. I am not familiar with await. pardon me, I am learning mongoose. Would you please provide me the whole actual code?

Comment: This is the error:      await People.insertMany([
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modul

Comment: await is used to wait for Promises to be completed thus only used in asynchronous functions. Please find updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use insertMany() to save many document in one time.
You can try this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    address: String
});
const People= mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);
const person = [
    {
        name: "john",
        age: 25,
        address: "New York, USA"
    },
    { 
    name: "Don",
    age: 30,
    address: "Chicago, USA"
    },
    {
    name: "Kahn",
    age: 34,
    address: "Dhaka, Bangladesh"
    }
];
People.insertMany(person, async(err, docs) {
    await docs.save();
});
```

You can read more about this in here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-insertMany